# getresultlist - query ok but data duplicate in List

Tags: java, hibernate, list, duplicates

I have a problem with `getResultList()`.
My query is OK when it's executed and return 700 results. 
In the return List, I had 700 results but the list contains duplicate data.
So I do not have all results.

```
    public List<EscaleCatalogueKaravel> obtenirListeEscaleKaravelSelonMarche(Integer refMarche, Integer refLangue) {
    List<EscaleCatalogueKaravel> listeEscales = entityManager.createQuery("select distinct  p from EscaleCatalogueKaravel p " +
            "where p.refMarche=:refMarche and p.refLangue=:refLangue group by idEscale  ")
            .setParameter("refMarche", refMarche)
            .setParameter("refLangue", refLangue)
            .getResultList();

    if (listeEscales == null || listeEscales.size() == 0) {
        return null;
    }
    return listeEscales;

}
```

Have you got an idea ?

Comment: Your query doesn't make much sense, and I'm surprised it even runs. group by serves when you have an aggregate function in your select clause (count, sum, avg, etc.). Try removing the group by. And also, returning null instead of an empty collection is bad practice. It forces the caller to check for null (as you're doing here, which is unnecessary because getResultList() never returns null)

Comment: @JB Nizet: Returning null is absolutely ok if it is mentioned as possible return value in the Javadoc, because it can avoid the superfluous creation of an empty list (if an error condition is detected before the query is executed - not the case in this example - here returning null really is superfluous).

Comment: @Johanna. In this case, return Collections.emptyList(). You will return an immutable empty list, and no superfluous object will be created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using MySQL, right? Oracle would not execute the query but throw an error instead.

For correct usage of the group by clause you're only allowed to select that rows (or expressions) which are also mentioned in the group by clause. If you select a row which is not  in the group by clause, this row might have different values for the members of one group. Which of these values the database should return? MySQL arbitrarily returns one of the possible values, but that is not correct.

In your query you either only do `select distinct idEscale from ...` or you group by all necessary columns and only select that ones or you drop your `group by` clause. By the way, distinct also can be used without group by, and distinct only should be used if really necessary because it makes the query slow.

Comment: Thank you to everyone.
I will try with distinct. I am hibernate beginner :)